# How do you run a python script (.py) on an uploaded file in django

Tags: python, django, sqlite, python-requests, elementtree

I have a question regarding handling downloaded files on Django. I have created a form that allows users to upload a file (XML Format). It is then saved in the media folder (MEDIA_URL). I have also created a 'Parser.py', a script that will find stuffs using Element Tree and will insert it to an SQLite database.

My question is where do I need to put this 'Parser.py' script so it can parse the uploaded file and insert the data to the database. Is it with the upload button or maybe in the views during the request?

Comment: You can add it in the end of the view as a function call. So that once the upload is done and the file is ready, your script and run.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you have setup `MEDIA_URL` in your settings

To access the `MEDIA_URL` in your parser use below code.

```
from django.conf import settings

media_url = settings.MEDIA_URL
path_to_the_file = media_url + "/uploaded_file.xml"
```